# How to debug "ERROR: Could not reach the worker node."?

Tags: bluedata-3.7, bluedata

I am trying to set up a gateway and a worker node on a BlueData 3.7 controller using SSH credentials.

I believe that I have met all the pre-requisites in the [docs](http://docs.bluedata.com/), however, I get an error trying to install the gateway and the worker in the Installation section of the controller UI:

The error I get for both hosts are:

> ERROR: Could not reach the worker node.

The URL for the errors are:

- http://x.x.x.x/bdswebui/logworker/?id=/api/v1/workers/4
- http://x.x.x.x/bdswebui/logworker/?id=/api/v1/workers/5

I have checked the logs on the gateway and the worker.  Both show:

```
# tree /var/log/bluedata/
/var/log/bluedata/
└── install

1 directory, 0 files
```

All hosts can ssh to each other without a password prompt.

No firewall is running:

```
# iptables --list
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I've deleted the worker while listening in with tcpdump on the worker:

```
# tcpdump -i eth0  -ttttnnvvS src host x.x.x.x and tcp
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
2019-08-17 00:08:41.570940 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 3977, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 48)
    x.x.x.x.39039 > y.y.y.y.22: Flags [S], cksum 0x6215 (correct), seq 1453535125, win 29200, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 9], length 0
    ...
    x.x.x.x.46064 > y.y.y.y.22: Flags [F.], cksum 0x564b (correct), seq 1997087540, ack 4031219947, win 238, length 0
2019-08-17 00:14:54.710739 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 15525, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    x.x.x.x.46064 > y.y.y.y.22: Flags [.], cksum 0x564a (correct), seq 1997087541, ack 4031219948, win 238, length 0
```

Checking port 46064 on the controller, I can see that it is coming from a beam process which gives me confidence the network connectivity is ok between the two machines:

```
# lsof -i -P -n | grep 46064
beam.smp  12714      root   16u  IPv4 498735      0t0  TCP x.x.x.x:46064->y.y.y.y:22 (ESTABLISHED)
```

What else can I do to debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debug information I needed could be found in the `/tmp` folder on the worker and gateway hosts, e.g.

```
/tmp/bd_prechecks.nnnnn.log
/tmp/bd_prechecks.nnnnn.log.xtrace
/tmp/bds-nnnnnnnnnnnnnn.log
/tmp/bds-nnnnnnnnnnnnnn.log.xtrace
/tmp/worker_setup_x.x.x.x-n-n-n-n-n-n
/tmp/worker_setup_x.x.x.x-n-n-n-n-n-n.xtrace
```

For more information, see http://docs.bluedata.com/37_step-1-troubleshooting